# Integration involving polynomial and exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

> Integrate the following function:
>   $$\int \frac{(x^2+1)e^x}{(x+1)^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried to simplify the function. However, that didn't get me anywhere. I'm aware of the identity: $$\int e^x(f(x) + f`(x)) \ \mathrm{d}x = e^xf(x)$$
However, I'm not sure how it would be applied here, or whether it would be applied here. How should I start the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}=1-\frac{2x}{(x+1)^2}.$$
Then
$$\frac x{(x+1)^2}=\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{(x+1)^2}$$
and you can apply your identity.

> $$e^x-2\dfrac{e^x}{x+1}+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

Doing partial fraction decomposition, we find that
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^2}=1-\frac{2}{1+x}+\frac{2}{(1+x)^2}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\int\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^2}e^x\,dx=\int e^x\,dx-\int\frac{2}{1+x}e^x+\int\frac{2}{(1+x)^2}e^x\,dx.
$$
Integrating the last term by parts, we find that
$$
\int\frac{2}{(1+x)^2}e^x\,dx=-\frac{2}{1+x}e^x+\int\frac{2}{1+x}e^x\,dx
$$
We conclude that one term cancel, and we get
$$
\int\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^2}e^x\,dx=e^x-\frac{2}{1+x}e^x+C.
$$

Comment: I thought that my mathjax just failed when typing, but I had forgo that mathjax here does not accept `\[` and `\]`, and that one is supposed to use `$$`.

Comment: Aha.... I applied partial fractions as well. Never thought that a term would cancel out... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int \frac{\left[\left(x^{2}+1+2 x\right)-2 x\right] e^{x}}{(x+1)^{2}} d x \\
&=\int e^{x} d x-2 \int \frac{x e^{x}}{(x+1)^{2}} d x \\
&=e^{x}-2 \cdot \frac{e^{x}}{x+1} +C\\
&=\frac{x-1}{x+1} e^{x}+C
\end{aligned}
$$